# Showing that for measurable $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, $L^1(\Omega; C_0(\mathbb{R}^n))$ is separable

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, measure-theory, integration

Here we're integrating "Banach-valued" functions $u: \Omega \rightarrow C_0(\mathbb{R}^n))$ , and by $u \in L^1(\Omega; C_0(\mathbb{R}^n))$ I mean that

$$\int_{x \in \Omega} \| u(x) \|_{\infty} < \infty. $$

In the middle of a proof in

- Ball J.M. (1989) *A version of the fundamental theorem for young measures*. In: Rascle M., Serre D., Slemrod M. (eds) *PDEs and Continuum Models of Phase Transitions*, Lecture Notes in Physics **344**, Springer,  doi:[10.1007/BFb0024945](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0024945), [author pdf](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/ball/Articles%20in%20Conference%20Proceedings%20and%20Books/Ball%20-%20Version%20of%20the%20Fundamental%20Theorem%20for%20Young%20Measures.pdf),

the author used this with no explanation, and I don't think it's obvious although I might be missing something. I've tried taking a given $u: \Omega \rightarrow C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and identifying with it a function from $\Omega \times \mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ by $u(x, A) = u(x)(A)$ in an attempt to get $L^1(\Omega; C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)) \subseteq L^1(\Omega \times \mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R})$ and use the separability of the latter space. I think this breaks down because you can't use that $\| \cdot \|_{L^1} \leq \| \cdot \|_{L^{\infty}}$ since $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not of finite measure, although there might be a way of using $u(x) \in C_0(\mathbb{R}^N)$ I can't see how to get this to fall out. Finally I suspect that linear combinations of functions of the form $ x \mapsto (\varphi_i(x) \cdot \psi_{j})_{ i, j\in \mathbb{N}}$ where the $\varphi_i$ are dense in $C^0(\Omega)$ and the $\psi_j$ dense in $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ (kinda like simple functions) will be dense in the desired space but I can't prove it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps $\Omega$ is assumed to be compact?

Comment: @WlodAA in the reference I'm looking at (J.M Ball A Version of the Fundamental Theorem of Young Measures)  $\Omega$ is simply taken to be some (Lebesgue) measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Does $\ C_0\ $ mean continuous functions which are $\ 0\ $ at infinity or are $0$ outside a compact set? Either way, if this is true then the given inequality is false.

Comment: @WlodAA by $C_0$ I mean $0$ at infinity, ie $\lim_{\|x \| \rightarrow \infty} (|f(x)|) = 0$. Which inequality would be false, sorry?

Comment: What is your exact definition of $L^1(\Omega;X)$ for a Banach space $X$? It should be clear that $L^1(\Omega) \otimes X$ is dense in it, so if $X$ is separable, the separability of $L^1(\Omega)$ immediately implies the separability of $L^1(\Omega;X)$.

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle the definition of $L^1(\Omega; X)$ that I've been working with is simply that a function $u: \Omega \rightarrow X$ belongs to $L^1(\Omega; X)$ whenever $\int_{\Omega} \| u(x) \|_X < \infty$. You're right though, I think that's a perfectly valid solution I've managed to gloss over. I suppose I was trying to do something similar with the collection of functions I was constructing above, but for whatever reason it didn't occur to me to just express things as a direct product as you have. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: (Never mind that "inequality", let's forget it).